# Android App stops when adding to request Queue of volley lib

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, android-volley

I'm trying to make a signup activity for my android app. I followed the tutorial at this link: [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).

This tutorial helped me connect my app to `MYSQL` database using a php api and the internet requests using volley library. After following the tutorial and applying its steps carefully, when I tried the app, the app stops before the signup process occurs. A window pops up saying: "Unfortunately, my app has stopped.". 
I kept tracing the code until I found the line causing the error, but I have no idea why is it causing such error or how to fix it. Below is my codes:

Signup activity (Main activity where signup data is entered and button clicked):

```
package com.example.coolpoolers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.os.Build;

import app.AppConfig;
import app.AppController;
import helper.SQLiteHandler;
import helper.SessionManager;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

public class SignUp extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = SignUp.class.getSimpleName();
private EditText inputFullName;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    findViewById(R.id.signupBt).setOnClickListener(signupBt);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this,
                AfterSignIn.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}

OnClickListener signupBt = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();



        if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

            registerUser(name, email, password);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
};

 /**
 * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
 * email, password) to register url
 * */
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
        final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            "MY IP", new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {

                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (!error) {
                            // User successfully stored in MySQL
                            // Now store the user in sqlite

                            String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                            JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                            String name = user.getString("name");
                            String email = user.getString("email");
                            String created_at = user
                                    .getString("created_at");

                            // Inserting row in users table
                            db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                            // Launch login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    SignUp.this,
                                    LogIn.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                            // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                            // message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "register");
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };
    strReq.getBodyContentType();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            tag_string_req, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    // Adding request to request queue
    **error line below**
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Below is the error log copied from logcat after pressing the signup button. Line 230 mentioned below where the error occurs is mentioned above in the code as: **error line below**

> E/AndroidRuntime(842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(842): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(842):    at
>   com.example.coolpoolers.SignUp.registerUser(SignUp.java:230)

AppController class where the error line calls its methods:

```
package app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Really any help is appreciated. I'm really stuck. Also if there is any data missing and you need me to add it in my code, that could help with defining the error or its cause tell me and I'll add it.

I'm using Eclipse Mars, java 1.7, SDK 19 up to 24 installed, ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the AppController Instance is giving the null pointer exception.
  Have u mentioned yourAppController in android manifest.
    `< application
        android:name="app.AppController"
    .......>
    </application>`